# JSX conditional inline styling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, jsx, inline-styles

I was trying to apply a conditional styling to textarea element. Its based on when a user clicks on a textarea its styles need to change accordingly. So I am maintaining a state of textarea using a boolean variable whom value changes when user clicks, in my style attribute I am trying to apply a style based on value of this boolean variable.

```
class InputContainer extends Component {
    let {name,type} = this.props;
    let clicked = false;
    let styles = {
      basic: {
       border: "5px solid blue";
      },
      clicked: {
        border: "2px solid green";
      }
    };
    function populateField() {
       switch(type) {
            case "textBox":
              return (
                <div>

                  <textarea rows="5" name={name} style={Object.assign({}, styles.basic, clicked && styles.clicked)} onClick={()=>{clicked=true;}}>
                  </textarea>
                </div>
              )
              break;
    }


    render() {
       return({populateFields})
    }

    }
    export default InputContainer;
```

*styles.basic* are getting applied successfully however *styles.clicked* aren't even if I click on textarea. This code doesn't work I needed to use className attribute with css instead.

Comment: you should use React state to manage your clicked variable.
If you do not do so, render method won't be called again when clicked value is changed. 
So your component would not be updated automatically.

Instead of `clicked = true` you should do `this.setState({clicked: true})`

Comment: Thanks man it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below updated and formatted code. Here I took one state variable i.e., border and passing that as border to style prop. By default the state border has "5px solid blue" and When onClick fires on textarea I am setting a new border style. as simple as that.

```
class InputContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      border: "5px solid blue"
    }
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(){
    this.setState({
      border: "2px solid green"
    })
  }
  let {name,type} = this.props;
    function populateField() {
       switch(type) {
          case "textBox":
            return (
              <div>
                <textarea rows="5" name={name} style={{border: this.state.border}} onClick={this.onClick}>
                </textarea>
              </div>
            )
            break;
        }

    render() {  
       return(
          {populateFields}
       )
    }

    }
    export default InputContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

React inline styles are different from CSS, for example

`basic: {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}`

Should be quoted like this:

`basic: {
  border: "5px solid blue"
}`

Comment: I missed quotes in post, in my actual code I applied it with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I helped you rewrite the entire code using the proper react way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class InputContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    clicked: false
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    this.setState({clicked: true})
  }

  populateField = () => {
    let {name, type} = this.props
    let {clicked} = this.state

    switch (type) {
      case "textBox":
        return (
          <div>
            <textarea
              rows="5"
              name={name}
              style={Object.assign({}, styles.basic, clicked && styles.clicked)}
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            />
          </div>
        )
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.populateField()
  }
}

const styles = {
  basic: {
    border: "5px solid blue",
  },
  clicked: {
    border: "2px solid green",
  }
}

export default InputContainer
```

---

The reason to why nothing happened after clicking on the textarea was because you're not using the component **states** to handle `clicked` variable.

It's very important to understand that `render()` function is called whenever there is a **state change**.

So you should make `clicked` a **state**, and use `this.setState()` to change it. When the `clicked` state has changed, `populateField()` will be executed again, but this time `styles.clicked` will be applied.